# conditionally load javascript & CSS for do_action() calls from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, actions, wp-enqueue-script

I am developing a plugin and using `do_action()` instead of shortcodes to display plugin content on the site.  The plugin will only be used by me, but I am making the plugin to separate components of the site from the theme itself.

How would I go about conditionally displaying javascript and css on a page, IF a specific do_action is called in a theme, from the plugin?

I have found a ton on shortcodes but I wanted to avoid using shortcodes, as I will be calling the actions directly in the theme.

I tried something like this

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'print_my_script');
function print_my_script() {
    if(did_action('my_custom_action')) {
        wp_enqueue_scripts('listings');
        wp_enqueue_scripts('isotope');
    }
}
```

**edit: its wp_enqueue_script() not scripts and changing that solved my problem**

but it did not work.  I also looked at Scribu's [article](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html) on the subject for shortcodes and use globals, but that still did not work.

I suspect that I might be able to rearrange priorities and make this work, but I am not sure.

Comment: have you tried the correct function - `wp_enqueue_script`?

Comment: @Milo wow. I had taken this code from Scribus article which used `wp_print_scripts()` and changed print to enqueue, and stopped there.  thank you! I am in shock that this worked.

Answer (score 1):

And.... the answer was actually correct, if you are using the correct functions.  As Milo pointed out, it's `wp_enqueue_script` not scripts.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'print_my_script');
function print_my_script() {
    if(did_action('my_custom_action')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('listings');
        wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
    } 
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in need!